# Android NotificationChannel ask permission at runtime for multiple channels?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-permissions

Explanation:
I send a message through fcm.
When the user receives message, notification is shown and an specific (out of multiple audio files which are in raw folder of app) audio file is played.
To play different audio messages, I just change the file name provided in jUri in below code.

This works below Android O but on => O
What do I want:
1. How do I ask for the runtime permission play these different audio files for different messages?
2. Also when I give the permissions manually, I hear the same audio message even if the jUri file name is different?
3. What is the difference between CHANNEL_ID and CHANNEL_NAME in NotificationChannel?
4. Should the code below "if()" check, be inside "else" part?

Following is my code:

```
Uri jUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" +getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.p);
String classnm = " FirebaseMessagingService ";

int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        Log.d("loog", classnm + "747 " + ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE+ "://" +getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+"/"+ R.raw.p );
        Log.d("loog", classnm + "748 " + jUri );
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(this.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            Log.d("loog", classnm + "690 ");
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
            mChannel.setDescription(CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION);
            mChannel.enableLights(true);
            mChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            mChannel.enableVibration(true);
//            mChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            mChannel.setShowBadge(false);
            AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                    .build();
            mChannel.setSound(jUri, audioAttributes);

            if (notificationManager != null)
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
        Log.d("loog", classnm + "703 ");

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setSound(jUri)
                .setContentText(message);
        Log.d("loog", classnm + "710 ");

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        Log.d("loog", classnm + "721 ");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the 2nd point you have noted, that same sound file is run on different channel names, just pass the CHANNEL_ID and CHANNEL_NAME dynamically.